# Python2.x/3.x compatibility: "Error: AttributeError: 'Instruction' object has no attribute 'identity_byte'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.6

Hello I am current facing the error message of the title when running my program. The `identity_byte` is clearly defined on the constructor, so I do not know why he is not finding it.

In fact, Python 2.6 does find it and runs my program without issues. But python 3.2 shows the error message.

Bellow the full output of running it under Python 3.2 and a nearly self-contained code example (the code it is self contained, but it needs a file as input)

```
class 'bytes'
class 'int'
120
216
169
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 76, in <module>
    main () 
  File "test.py", line 73, in main
    cpu.process_instructions ()
  File "test.py", line 58, in process_instructions
    instruction.process ()
  File "test.py", line 18, in process
    print ("Identifier Byte: {}".format(self.identity_byte))
AttributeError: 'Instruction' object has no attribute 'identity_byte'
```

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import argparse

HEADER_SIZE = 16
KB_SIZE = 16384

class Instruction (object):
    __metaclass_ = ABCMeta

    def __init__ (self,identification_byte):
        identity_byte = identification_byte

    def test (self):
        print ("BOTO")

    @abstractmethod
    def process (self):
        print ("Identifier Byte: {}".format(self.identity_byte))

    @abstractmethod
        def process2 (self):
            print ("Identifier Byte2: ", self.identity_byte)


class LDAInstruction (Instruction):
    def process (self):
       super.process ()

    def process2 (self):
       super.process()

 class ROM (object) :
    def __init__ (self, rom_bytes): 
       self.header = rom_bytes [0:HEADER_SIZE]
       self.temp = self.header [4]
       print (type (self.header))
       self.num_prg_blocks = 2#struct.unpack ("I", self.temp)
       print (type (self.num_prg_blocks))
       self.data_bytes = rom_bytes [HEADER_SIZE:HEADER_SIZE + (16 + KB_SIZE * int (self.num_prg_blocks))]
       self.total_size = 16 + KB_SIZE * self.num_prg_blocks

    def get_byte (self, pc):
        return  (self.data_bytes [pc])

class CPU (object):
    def __init__(self, rom_bytes):
        self.registers = []
        self.rom = ROM (rom_bytes)
        self.pc = 0

    def process_instructions (self):
       for byte in self.rom.data_bytes:
          byte = self.rom.get_byte (self.pc)
          self.pc+=1
          print (byte)
          if (byte == 169):
             instruction = Instruction (byte)
             instruction.process ()
             instruction.process2 ()
          if (self.pc == 3):
             break

def main ():

   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser (description='NES EMULATOR'); 
   parser.add_argument ('rom_path',metavar='R',type=str,help='path to the rom')
   args=parser.parse_args()

   with open (args.rom_path, 'rb') as file:
     rom_bytes = file.read ()           

   cpu = CPU(rom_bytes)
   cpu.process_instructions ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main ()
```

I do not know why this is happening, since I create an instance of `Instruction` with:

```
instruction = Instruction (byte)
```

so I expect that already is a member variable `identity_byte` for it in the instance.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Beside the point, but Python 2.6 and 3.2 are both really old and no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `self` on line 11:

```
identity_byte = identification_byte
```

It should be

```
self.identity_byte = identification_byte
```

---

By the way, you need to make a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the future. Here's mine:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        bar = bar

f = Foo(9)
print(f.bar)
```

Output in Python 3.6:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(f.bar)
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Output in Python 2.6 is the same except the last line:

```
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'bar'
```

Comment: Well, the code is self contained. It does need a file as input, however...